# Eclipse editor automatically deletes and restructures lines of text

Tags: eclipse, text

I have this issue: a brand new .properties file I checked from the revision control. I open it in notepad, no problems. I open it in eclipse, and I see that eclipse has automatically deleted (and compressed in some cases) lines of text.

How to control this behaviour and turn it off? It's very strange.

The encoding is ISO-8859.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It did not change your file. It just "folded" some lines it believes should be grouped. The only thing that is affected is how it is displayed. To disable folding you can go to `Window->Preferences->General->Editors->Structured Text Editors` and uncheck "Enable folding":

[image]

Comment: a small wrinkle is that I am using MyEclipse, so I don't have the option to choose "Structured Text Editors". Any workaround?

Comment: I don't know what "MyEclipse" is. Another thing you can do is just to right-click in the editor window and select preferences in the context menu and see which options you have there.

Comment: found it! it's in Window -> Preferences -> MyEclipse -> Files and Editors -> Common Editor Preferences -> Enable Folding. Still the right answer though. THANKS!